# Get pid of Chrome tab via terminal

Tags: macos, google-chrome, terminal, command-line-interface, pid

Is it possible to get the pid of a specific Google Chrome tab (like the current one) via the command line? Getting it via [`AppleScript`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AppleScript) would be an acceptable solution.

My use case is [limiting the CPU usage](https://github.com/opsengine/cpulimit) of a specific tab, so for now my solution to get its pid, since it’ll be the tab with the highest cpu usage, is

```
ps -Ao %cpu,pid,args | grep 'Google Chrome Helper' | sort --reverse | head -1 | awk '{ print $2 }'
```

which definitely works. However, were there to be a “cleaner” way, by probing Chrome directly, that’d be preferable.

Comment: I don't know also a way to achieve this and I am interested in a solution. 

Also with autohotkey you only get the browser PID and not the current tab PID see  https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/74322-winget-returns-wrong-pid-for-chromeexe/

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't directly answer your question but you can get the process ID of a tab through the Chrome Task Manager. Open `Window` > `Task Manager`.

Comment: Yes, I know, but I’m really looking for a CLI-only solution.

Answer (score -2):

You can use `shift`+`esc` to open google chrome task manager.. and get pid for each tab and process..

Comment: The questions says “via the command line”. This is no different than the other answer.